# Rails saving decimal without precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decimal

I've got a column named 'extra_charge'
This was the last migration for this column:

```
def self.up      
  change_column :menu_entries, :extra_charge, :decimal, precision: 8, scale: 2
end
```

But I can't save the number with decimals.

```
[2] pry(main)> c.extra_charge = '4,90'
=> "4,90"
[3] pry(main)> c.save
=> true
[4] pry(main)> c.extra_charge.to_f
=> 4.0
```

I've also tried a float, but this is not as accurate like the decimal, so I changed back to decimal. But I can't fix it.

Comment: What if you use `4.90`?

Comment: @Iceman [5] pry(main)> c.extra_charge = 4,90  => [4, 90]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Iceman said there is a typo.

Replace `,` with `.`

Example

```
[2] pry(main)> c.extra_charge = '4.90'
=> "4.90"
[3] pry(main)> c.save
=> true
[4] pry(main)> c.extra_charge.to_f
=> 4.9
```

Comment: okay, this works... sorry for the misunderstanding. so I have to find a way to use ',' as default separator